# What do I do if I can't find ssl.conf file in a CentOS server?

Tags: centos, ssl

I'm preparing a new CentOS Linux server, one of many.
When I try to configure SSL on this server, I noticed there is no `ssl.conf` file. Not in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` and not in `/etc/httpd/conf/ssl.conf`.

I also tried `locate ssl.conf` and got no result.

Do I need to create it myself?
Can I copy the file from the other CentOS server I have? Is it OK to do that?

Centos 6.3(64bit), Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) , PHP Version 5.3.3, MySQLi 5.1.73

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to install `mod_ssl`. Run:

```
sudo yum install mod_ssl
```

And it will place the default configuration file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

If for some reason you have `mod_ssl` installed, but the file is not there and yum says `Nothing to do`, try to reinstall with:

```
sudo yum reinstall mod_ssl
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. i did that and it writes "nothing to do" - Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.syn.co.il
 * extras: centos.syn.co.il
 * updates: centos.syn.co.il
Setting up Install Process
Package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.15-47.el6.centos.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: but is still created the file :) (although it wrote "already installed")

Comment: That's interesting, I just booted 6.3 to check... I removed the file and install did not put it back, but then `sudo yum reinstall mod_ssl` did.

Comment: @techraf Its very helpful post and time consuming thanks

Comment: For anyone doing install on Amazon EC2 with httpd24 installed, please try `sudo yum install mod24_ssl`

Comment: If you're getting `Package(s) mod_ssl available, but not installed.
Error: Nothing to do`

Try `yum search mod_ssl ` then `then yum install mod_ssl.XX <- as listed from yum search output.` (src: https://serverfault.com/questions/355481/installing-mod-ssl-on-centos)